# Is there a correct way to link to an acumatica popup URL from an external application

Tags: acumatica

We are bringing in an external javascript app into the center of an acumatica page template. within this javascript app, we are putting in links to open up popups to acumatica urls...to be more specific, this javascript app is a search catalog that will display style and serial items. and from here, we are opening up popups to the correct screens within acumatica.

So we have it all setup, as we just copied and pasted urls that we saw existed and stripped out some of the parameters (like timestamp for example). We kept the popup panel parameter in place. But we are seeing some issues where some of the page content seems cached from one item to the next, so i'm concerned that we are doing this incorrectly.

Wondering if anyone knows the best/proper way to link from an external application to an acumatica popup to avoid such issues.And what parameters are required and acceptable values, etc...

Comment: Just a follow-up, this had nothing to do with the external url structure.

Comment: For me it sounds like you want to achieve link sharing of some particular entity from Acumatica. Am I right?

Comment: @YuriyZaletskyy we resolved the actual issue that caused the content to cache/not update. But I would be curious to know if their is a best practice way to link to existing screens within acumatica. As mentioned in the original post, we are opening up a javascript modal with the acumatica screen inside of it. Low non pressing request/priority. Many thanks as always for the reply.

Comment: you mean creation of links between pages inside of Acumatica?

Answer (score 0):

The standard structure for most URLs in Acumatica is:

```
https://[Address]/Main?CompanyID=[Tenant]&ScreenId=[Screen](&[Key1]=[Value1]&[Key2]=[Value2]...)
```

Where:

- **Address** : Is the application FQDN like `mycompany.acumatica.com`
- **Tenant** : Is the tenant name of tenant you are linking to. This is the company you select on login, if you only have one tenant it can be ommited. If you don't know your tenant and tenant name it is in the tenants screen (SM203530), it is DAC field `UPCompany.CompanyCD`.
- **Screen** : Is the screen ID of the screen you are linking to.

Screen ids use the following convention (You can read more about it in the [Acumatica reference](https://help-2019r2.acumatica.com/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=4a5e6db8-cbba-4cbe-b0f1-1d774381c1b4)):

```
 XX999999
 | | | |_ Subscreen Sequential Number
 | | |___ Screen Sequential Number
 | |_____ Screen Type: 
 |                    10: Setup
 |                    20: Maintenance
 |                    30: Data Entry
 |                    40: Inquiry 
 |                    50: Processing
 |                    60: Reports
 |_______ Two-Letter Module Code
```

- **Key1,Value1, etc...** : You can append to the URL any defined DAC keys and the required values to point to a specific document. For example, AR screen AR301000 uses DocType and RefNbr.

Be aware that you need to make sure the linked screen is configured in the site map and that the user using the link has access permissions for it and the linked document.